# Windows Complete Backup

Tags: linux, windows, backup

I'm looking to try Linux. How do I completely backup my Windows computer and put it into something like an ISO so I can boot from it later if I ever want to switch back from Linux to Windows? Will create system image work if I want to completely re-install Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a disk large enough to handle such an image, it will also be large enough for you to install a Linux-based system onto. In which case, I'd suggest you simply swap disks and use the "other" to try out a Linux-based distribution. If you decide you want to revert you can just swap back the disks.

Comment: What if I'm on a laptop?, I have a external USB that I want to back up to

Comment: Fair enough. Windows Backup should be able to get you a full backup from which you can restore. Do you have a Windows installation disk, so that you can run enough of Windows to restore the backup image?

Comment: Yeah, I think so will I have to reuse the verification code for windows? because the label that has is really hard to read because it wore down

Comment: Sorry, not 100% sure on that.

Comment: It would be a full system backup so I see no reason why you should need to re-validate Windows. However, as I mentioned I cannot be 100% sure on that.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to learn linux... and you want to backup windows.

First off, you don't have to destroy your windows installation to play with linux. You can install VirtualBox to run virtual machines under windows.

Download a "linux install iso" for installation onto a virtual machine, and you'll have the same experience as if you were installing linux on a "real" computer.

Playing with virtual machines can make experimenting easier and safer. You can create a separate virtual machine for different flavors of linux (CentOS, Debian, Ubuntu), while not risking your windows install.

Another option is to create a bootable aka "live" linux install on a usb stick. This is a linux system installed on a bootable usb stick. Ubuntu provides a good set of instructions...

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

For backing up, its probably best to go with whatever Windows Backup provides, or perhaps a commercial solution like Norton Ghost.

An open source alternative is Mondo Rescue, which specifically does what you want: "creating a bootable set of rescue CD/DVDs". But you need to know linux to use it... Or Clonezilla... "The Free and Open Source Software for Disk Imaging and Cloning".

http://clonezilla.org/